# How to update a specific table of a webpage in flask?

Tags: flask

I am using flask 2.0 and there is a table on my webpage that shows the status of the transaction. Actually, the status is being updated by calling a MySQL DB hosted in my server. And the table is only updated with the latest data once the webpage is refreshed fully. Is there a way that I can call the MySQL DB and update just the table when I check refresh button next to the table?

The current code and extract is shown below:

```
Flask App:

cursor.execute('Select * from process WHERE email=%s ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 20', (email,))
transactions = cursor.fetchall()
return render_template('clientarea.html', transactions=transacions)

HTML:
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm" style="text-align:center">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 25%">Date</th>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 25%">Process Count</th>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 25%">Completed Process</th>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 25%">Failed Process</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
                {% for transaction in transactions %}
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                      <td>{{ transaction.get('date').strftime("%d %B, %Y") }}</td>
                      <td>{{ transaction.get('pcount') }}</td>

                      <td>{{ transaction.get('pcompleted') }}</td>
                      <td>{{ transaction.get('pfailed') }}</td>

                </tr>

              </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Is it possible to load the updated value without refreshing the page using flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AJAX

> Insert this code into head tag in html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#refreshBtn').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'http://localhost:5000/table-refresh',
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(val) {
                        $('#date_' + data[val][0]).html(data[val][1]);
                        $('#pcount_' + data[val][0]).html(data[val][2]);
                        $('#pcompleted_' + data[val][0]).html(data[val][3]);
                        $('#pfailed_' + data[val][0]).html(data[val][4]);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Grant id in table rows, add new refresh button

```
<td id="date_{{ transaction.id }}">{{ transaction.get('date').strftime("%d %B, %Y") }}</td>
<td id="pcount_{{ transaction.id }}">{{ transaction.get('pcount') }}</td>
<td id="pcompleted_{{ transaction.id }}">{{ transaction.get('pcompleted') }}</td>
<td id="pfailed_{{ transaction.id }}">{{ transaction.get('pfailed') }}</td>
<input type="button" id="refreshBtn" value="refresh" />
```

Finally, create new router for refreshing table

```
@app.route('/table-refresh', methods=['GET'])
def table_refresh():
    # [[id, date, pcount, pcompleted, pfailed], ...]
    arr = [[1, '2021-08-23', 1, 1, 1], [2, '2021-08-24', 1, 1, 1]]
    return jsonify(arr)
```